# Change char* to point a few bits offset

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, byte, bit

Say I have this code:

```
char  num[2] = {15, 240};
char* p_num;
```

Now,  if I have understood everything correct, the bits in the array should be aligned like this:

```
00001111 11110000
```

**My question is:** Is there any possible way to make the pointer p_num to point to the four last bits in the first byte so that when I execute this code:

```
printf("%d", *p_num);
```

255 will be written?

I.e. p_num will point to the bits which the brackets below encloses:

```
0000[1111 1111]0000
```

Comment: Your premise is incorrect.  Alignment has to do with addressing and no addressing is made inside an individual `char` normally.  Almost no cpu architecture today allows you to address individual bits of a `char`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The minimum addressable unit of memory is a byte (at best), though you could obtain the desired value using

```
((num[0] & 0xF) << 4) | ((num[1] >> 4) & 0xF)
```

For example,

```
unsigned char num[2] = {15, 240};
unsigned char combined = ((num[0] & 0xF) << 4) | ((num[1] >> 4) & 0xF);
printf("%d\n", (int)combined);
```

Note that I used `unsigned char` to store `240` and `255` since `char` can be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation.

Comment: Technically, in C the language itself does not assume byte-addressable memory. That is implementation dependent.

Comment: @verbose, There are machines can only address units larger than a byte, but I'm not familiar with any machine that can address something smaller than a byte.

Comment: Yes,  I managed to get the value when I  wrote 15 | 240,  but -1 was printed when I tried a[0] | a[1]. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because your implementation uses signed `char`s

Comment: Aha, thank you :) I don't really get what the reason for doing what you did above. Aren't you just moving the bits around so that 240 becomes 15 and 15 beomes 240, thus makiing it equal to the much simpler a[0] | a[1], i.e. 15 | 240?

Comment: @ikegami Whether or not such machines exist is irrelevant to the grammar of the language itself. There is no guaranteed way to achieve the result the OP wants.

Comment: @Donkey King, They are not the same. What if you started with `0xAB` and `0xCD`? Your method would give `0xEF` instead of `0xCB`

Comment: @verbose Re "*Whether or not such machines exist is irrelevant to the grammar of the language itself.*", I never said otherwise. Re "*There is no guaranteed way to achieve the result the OP wants*", I know. I explained why in my answer.

Comment: @ikegami As you yourself say, there are machines that can address only units larger than a byte. So what is the basis for your saying *The memory is only byte-addressable*? It might not be that. If you want to defend your answer, fine, but I disagree that it provides any reliable way to do what the OP wants. You yourself have had to revise it once it became clear that the OP's machine used signed `char` by default. So the correct answer to the question is simply **No**, and everything else is just based on chance.

Comment: @verbose, Re "*So what is the basis for your saying The memory is only byte-addressable?*", Educated guess. Feel free to prove me wrong by asking about the OP's hardware. But I've generalized the answer for you. /// Re "*I disagree that it provides any reliable way to do what the OP wants*", Why do you think that? Not only should it work for the OP, it should provide the exact same result regardless of machine.

Comment: I don't think that something which *typically* works is bulletproof enough; if it's good enough for you and the OP, fine, he is at liberty to upvote/accept. I made my own view clear in my own answer, and I don't find your arguments persuasive. Besides, you keep editing your answer to address the difficulties and objections inherent in it, and then tell me "it will work, and you are wrong to say it won't!" Such shifting ground is not a rational basis for discussion, and I'm done here.

Comment: @verbose, Re "*I don't think that something which typically works is bulletproof enough*", Again I ask, what makes you think it doesn't always work? If there's a problem, let me know and I'll fix it. Saying there's a problem and refusing to identify it isn't constructive.

Answer (score 0):

No, for two reasons.

1. In C, the size of a `char` is defined to be 1. However, **the unit itself is implementation dependent**. C does not guarantee that it will be 1 *byte*. Granted the unit is typically 1 byte. However, since this is not guaranteed, your premise that the bits in the bytes of the array will be arranged as you believe is not accurate. Strictly speaking, the bits themselves could contain anything. Though it would be unusual to have something else, based on the language you cannot *rely* on that arrangement of bits. Any workaround that relies on bit shifts, etc, will reliably work only on that implementation and cannot be assumed to be portable.
2. A pointer to `char` will only point to a `char`. If you advance it using pointer arithmetic, it will advance by 1 of whatever the implementation defined unit is. The same is true for,pointers to any other type. There is no way provided by the language to advance a pointer by fractions of whatever the size of the type is that the pointer points to.

Comment: I didn't really get the bold part. When I read The C Programming Language book they state that a char is one byte. Do you mean that one byte can be different on different systems?

Comment: @Donkey King, Definitely. For example, there are 9-bit signal processors, the the machine that controls the nuclear reactor at Bruce "B" uses a machine (Varian72) in which the smallest addressable unit is 16-bits.

Comment: Okey, I just read at wikipedia that a byte is the smallest addressable unit in a system, so it would be logical that it can be different on different platforms.